# $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \frac{H_{2n}}{n^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

Recently I tried to estimate this sum but without much success, would you have any methods to suggest?

$S=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \frac{H_{2n}}{n^2}$

Comment: Since you want to estimate it, and is an alternating sum with decreasing terms, the sum is between any two consecutive partial sums.

Comment: Also, Wolfram Alpha says
sum_(n=1)^∞ ((-1)^n sum_(k=1)^(2 n) 1/k)/n^2≈-1.14961134098672142140504700316342630968969743214600308575545207339825767678712015922092651572286220525471

Comment: How did you try to estimate it? Also what else have you tried?

Comment: There is almost certainly a duplicate of this sum on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128277/how-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nn2h-2n). Found using approach0.xyz

Comment: Thanks @VarunVejalla the closest I could find was a solution for $\sum (-1)^n \dfrac{\color{red}{H_n}H_{2n}}{n^2}$

Comment: thanks you so much @VarunVejalla !!!