# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^4)}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

I'm trying to evaluate
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^4)}{x}dx$$
I used the series expansions for $\ln(1-x)$ and managed to get a double summation out of them
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+4m)}$$
Does anyone know how to go about computing this sum? I know that this has a closed form involving Apery's Constant and Catalan's constant but I'm unsure how to tackle this double summation.

Comment: Does [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1885478p12843690) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the referenced integrals below
[$$I_1= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx=\frac{11}8\zeta(3)\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4126183/686284) [$$I_2= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx=\frac{23}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac\pi2 G$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4136441/686284)
to obtain

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^4)}{x}dx= I_1+I_2=\frac{67 }{32}\zeta (3)-\frac{\pi }{2}G$$